# PHP hashed & salted password

Tags: php

So I'm creating a simple PHP register/log in form. I have created a hash & salt for the password, but I can't seem to log in using the correct password. As in it's hashing it incorrectly? Bare in mind I'm not a pro.

Registration code, works fine, hashes the pw & stores the salt.

```
if ($errors === 0) {
            $salt = mcrypt_create_iv(32); 
            $signpassword = DatabaseHelpers::hash($signpassword, $salt);
            query("INSERT INTO user_info(Username, Email, Password, Salt) VALUES(:signusername, :email, :signpassword, :salt)",
            array('signusername' => $signusername, 'email' => $email, 'signpassword' => $signpassword, 'salt' => $salt),
            $conn);
            $successstatus = 'You have successfully registered';
}  
};
```

The log in code

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

function verify($password, $salt) {
 hash('sha256', $password . $salt);
    }//function for verifying the password, doesn't seem to be working

if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    $logstatus = 'Please input your username and password';
    //update login attempts
} else {

    $salts = $conn->prepare('SELECT salt FROM user_info where username=?');
    $salts->bindParam(1, $username);
    $salts->execute();
    $salts = $salts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($salts as $slt) {
        $slt = $salt;
    }//gets the salt

    $hashedpassword = verify($password, $salt);//
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM user_info where username=? and password=?');
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $username);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $hashedpassword);
    $stmt->execute();

    function start($username, $sessionName){
        header(  'Location: logging.php') ;
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
    };


    if($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
       start($username, $sessionName);
    } else {
        $logstatus = 'Username or password incorrect.';
    }
};};};
```

It always does the else statement, when I input the correct password. If I comment out the hashing and put in the hashed pw from the database, it logs me in? I know it's probably something really dumb but I can't see it. Anyone help me out? It's driving me crazy -_-

------------------Okay guys, remember, I'm not an expert.

I tested it again with the return and found out the two passwords result to two completely different passwords.

75642f23ef3c7b35d0a5e223a9c3187d102e77dcc121b5d08c7bbcb44de73e2c 
6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b

I don't know. Spent too much time on this stupid salting stuff, was just trying to learn -_-, guess I'll go with the built in hashing functions and never learn from my mistake, sigh...

Yeah, not everyone has PHP 5.5 so I can't use those built in functions.

Comment: Please use `password_hash` instead of your own custom function http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: you could save yourself a lot of trouble and use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: Why do you use `DatabaseHelpers::hash` in one place and a separate `verify` function in the other? Shouldn't they be doing the same thing?

Comment: I was having errors so I divided it into a different function to figure out the problem and I just haven't changed it back yet.

Comment: You could have said it only works in PHP 5.5...not every server has 5.5...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your verify function doesn't actually **DO** anything. It sha256 hashes the salted/password, and then simply throws away that hash. Since there's no `return` in the function, the calling code simply gets a `NULL` value.

You probably want something like:

```
function verify($pass, $salt) {
   return hash('sha256', $pass . $salt);
   ^^^^^^----note the return call.
}

if ($hashed_password_from_database == verify($password_from_form, $salt))
```

Comment: Additionally, the verify() function should actually verify the password. Right now, it just hashes it--which means its not actually doing what it's describing. Further, the verify function should safely compare the hashes, right now its vulnerable to a time-based attack.